# The content tag makes me discontent

Tags: discussion, tags

[content](/questions/tagged/content) has no tag wiki or description, and seems like the wrong sort of meta tag.

I feel like we need more dis-content in our lives. Are there any arguments for keeping the tag, and suggestions if so on how to actually use it?